# Proper etiquette for questions which branch

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, etiquette

Often times I find the answers/comments to my question raise other highly related questions like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8059180/how-secure-is-apt-get-install-when-sudo-access-given-via-sudoers-file/8059233#8059233). I asked about the security of giving users `sudo` access of `apt-get install` and user sarnold [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8059180/how-secure-is-apt-get-install-when-sudo-access-given-via-sudoers-file/8059224#8059224) repositories in `/etc/apt/sources.list` or `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/*`.

Do I ask him about those repositories there in the comment section? Do I modify the question? Do I message him directly (is that even possible)? If I create a new question, should I mention that I got the inspiration for the question in a previous question? Should I indicate to user sarnold that he should check out my new question? It would be great if there was a way to link questions together.

More to the point, why is there no wiki here for how to use this site (at least I am not aware of one). I need advice on what voice to use, how detailed my question should be, when I should reference my sources...

Comment: To answer your last question: meta IS the 'wiki' for stackoverflow.  If you have any questions you just post them here, as you have done :)  There's also an faq on the top right of the screen, next to the search bar.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Mostly people are not super-picky about these things (cue a list of all the etiquette violations in this answer), but since you asked:

> Do I ask him about those repositories there in the comment section?

If you need clarification on an answer, then sure, ask in the comment section. That's what it's there for.

> Do I modify the question?

Not in this case. Generally, once your question has actually been answered, you probably don't need to edit additional content into it. Modifying the question would be appropriate when you have new details that are relevant to solving your original problem (such as the outcome of a debugging procedure that someone suggested in a comment).

> Do I message him directly (is that even possible)?

No (no). Better to keep communication on the site where it can help future visitors.

> If I create a new question, should I mention that I got the inspiration for the question in a previous question?

Sure, why not? It helps provide context for people answering the new question. But even if you don't mention it, people will probably notice that your questions are related anyway.

> Should I indicate to user sarnold that he should check out my new question?

If you want, sure, you can leave a comment ("I asked a followup question here, could you look at it?"). But sarnold (in this case) is under no obligation to follow your suggestion.

> It would be great if there was a way to link questions together.

There is, it's called linking. :-P

Hyperlinking, specifically. You put a hyperlink to one question in another question, and the cross-reference gets displayed under the "Linked" heading at the right side of each question's page.