# A specific question has been revised 16 times...what to do?

Tags: discussion, edits, specific-question, revisions-list

I have a specific situation for which I require the input of the community before I take action, because I am not confident enough in my evaluation of the situation to take the appropriate action.

I answered [Auto Copy & Paste specific columns depending on ComboBox value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19977563/auto-update-columns-depending-on-combobox-value) about 2 weeks ago, but the OP of the question has now edited the question so many times, my answer no longer makes sense, in fact he integrated my answer into the question and now is asking about another problem.

From [Exit strategies for "chameleon questions"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions), I am aware that the normal actions for such situations are:

1. Rollback the Edit
2. [Leave a Comment to the OP to explain](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130630/182513)
3. Delete my answer
4. Edit my answer to match the new question.

However, this user has been known to do this same exact thing previously, in fact [NullPointerException while reading txt file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18397564/nullpointerexception-while-reading-txt-file) was also converted to CW because he edited too many times.

I've already done step #2, I left a comment to try to explain, but I'm at a loss on how to handle this.  I don't really want to edit my answer to address his new problem as I don't want to encourage this activity, so I'm left with trying to decide whether to delete my answer or rollback his edit so my answer is within the scope of the question.

I would appreciate the input of some more experienced users on how I should handle this specific case?  And possibly offer some guidelines on how to make this decision in the future.

Comment: So how is this not a dupe of the 'how to deal with Chameleon questions' post?

Comment: Sorry, but how isn't it a duplicate? You have a chameleon question and you are looking for a strategy to deal with it. Looks perfectly duplicate-y to me.

Comment: Your post is a text-book example of a duplicate Meta question.

Comment: it feels like I am trying to take this a step further because I have already dealt with this user before. He has been told not to edit his questions but he still does that. I know I will not help in the future but I dont want to be receiving downvotes for an answer that was valid originally. This is unfair toward me as I have taken the time to read and help. There should be a moderator or system in place that would sort these types of issues. Like I said I want to know if I should roll-back the question to the original state or delete my answer?

Comment: @mehow well, in such case just flag and let moderators deal with that user. They can send him official warning then suspend him if he refuse to follow the rules.

Comment: sorry If I have been unclear I have pointed out my specific question

Comment: Answer: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130630/147191.

Comment: Sorry but question itself still looks dupe to me. And for users who do the same offence again and again, there is only one answer: flag for moderator's attention.

Comment: I have quoted the Chameleon case as the first sentence, so I do realize its related! it's not a dupe because I have a specific question related to this specific case. There is no point to send a link to the Exit strategies as I am already aware of that! If you haven't already noticed I have left the OP a comment about editing his questions and changing the meaning.

Comment: @mehow the reason for the dup is so we don't have the same post asking the same thing over and over again.  The answers are in the answers of that question.  You have to decide how to best handle this, but if the OP here is a serial "chameleon" then flagging is probably your only outlet.

Comment: And here...  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188625/etiquette-for-russian-doll-questions

Comment: Id appreciate a constructive answer from a more experienced user than me explaining which of the two options I selected would be better in terms of moderation.

Comment: totally not a dupe. Soon to be a 10K I'd rather do a proper moderation than just pointing to a duplicate which doesn't solvet he problem.... thanks for everyones time and contribution.

Comment: Well it's a question about specific situation... that happens to be textbook example of something described in more general question. Sorry, but I honestly don't understand how copy-pasting answers from general question should help anybody. For these 2 choices, [there was an answer covering them](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/43480/225745) already. By a moderator. What more could you possibly want?

Comment: @mehow Tried to edit the question to reflect what I think you were trying to say.  I think the specific case is unique enough that it might require a different answer.  If I put too many words into your mouth, feel free to edit or rollback.

Comment: @psubsee2003 youve done great with your edit - still Molot is going to come and vote as a duplicate though. ,thanks for the effort much appreciated

Comment: @mehow it is a dup, but sometimes there is some wiggle room for specific cases in my opinion.  But you need to watch the attitude.  Honestly, had I read your comment indirectly at 10K users before I started editing, I probably wouldn't have been inclined to help.

Comment: @psubsee2003 I meant that I am soon going to be 10K and would rather join the team of the 10K as fully qualified member and someone who just happens to be 10K+. I see nothing wrong with that and I am not fully understanding what you meant in your last comment.

Comment: I'm not a 10K user, but if a question substantially changes meaning, I have no hesitation in rolling back without consulting a higher-rep user; such edits are plainly unfair to people who have already answered. I'll usually add a note to assuage hurt feelings, since 99% of the time, the OP just hasn't thought about it, rather than trying to inconvenience readers.

Comment: @mehow sorry if I misinterpreted, but I read it as somewhat insulting to 10K users.

Comment: @psubsee2003 that was my impression too. totally not what I meant to say I am glad you pointed this out as it gives me a chance to explain so no hurt feeling are left

Comment: essentially, behavior of the asker can be considered an abuse of [meta-tag:rate-limiting]: they use single post to ride a series of questions through it - this sets a bad example for users willing to circumvent existing limitation, see [Is there a limit on how many questions I can ask?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/4359/165773) and [Why are we limited to six questions per day?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127567/165773)