# New Help Center article for constant changing questions

Tags: feature-request, help-center, faq-proposed, help-center-proposed

Most of us know this:

1. [How to deal with constant changing questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252113/how-to-deal-with-constant-changing-questions)
2. [Etiquette for Russian Doll Questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188625/etiquette-for-russian-doll-questions)
3. [Exit strategies for "chameleon questions"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions)
4. [Dealing with solutions that end with a new error](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300966/dealing-with-solutions-that-end-with-a-new-error)

I propose to add a new point / article under [Help Center > Asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) or in the community [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites), mainly so we can link to it in comments. Proposed title:

> Why I should not change an answered question.

Proposed text:

> Question on this site are not only for short-term solutions to your problem but also to provide answers for other users in the future who face the same or similar questions. To achieve this it is important to keep questions and answers in sync which each other and focused on specific issues.
>
> You can always edit a question to add more information and clarify it. But after an answer adresses your question you should not change the meaning of it. Instead ask a new question for the new topic or issue (and link to the previous question for context if it makes sense).

Please feel free to contribute to the proposed text in the [community wiki answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/274502/235872) below, I am not much of a writer.

Comment: And by the way, if you want to add one post to the FAQ, you can edit the question and add the [tag:faq-proposed] tag.

Answer (score 4):

*Here the proposed answer as community wiki for all users to contribute:*

---

> Questions on this site are not only for short-term solutions to your problem but also to provide answers for other users in the future who face the same or similar questions. To achieve this, it is important to keep questions and answers synchronized with each other and focused on specific issues.
>
> You can always edit a question to add more information and clarify it. However, after an answer addresses your question you should not change the meaning of your question. Instead, please ask a new question for the new topic or issue (and link to the previous question for context if it makes sense).